# Ensure that a modular dependency of a shared library is compiled

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a library named A.so. This shared lib works on a set of interfaces, and has a header that defines a "void init()" method, but doesn't implement it. Also, this method is never called in the scope of A.so.

Then I have a library named B.so, which implements these interfaces, like a backend. Also, this library implements the init method (and maybe the main method which calls it, if the target will be a executable). But I'm not specifying it's dependencies. This means that a ldd -r -d B.so would give a lot of undefined errors, which is ok.

When I create a target executable which implements the init method, everything works fine because when linking the undefined references are shown and I can manually add them to the executable.

The problem is when the backend is another shared library C.so and it doesn't implements the "void init()" method. Since the A.so library has no "hard" dependencies over B.so and so the linkage of C.so doesn't include the definitions of B.so, thus making a dlopen over C.so fail because of the undefined references.

I know that an easy way to force A.so to depend on B.so is to define a dummy method and call it somewhere in A code, but I've found it somewhat lame so I'm asking here to see if there is a better way to do this.

Example:

```
A.so (no dependencies)

B.so (compilation spec 1)
   \ X.so
   \ Y.so

B.so (compilation spec 2)
   \ O.so
   \ Q.so

C.so 
   \ A.so
   \ B.so (this is not being included as A nor C link explicitly against B)

D.exe
   \ A.so
   \ B.so (this is include because D.exe has to implement the "void init()")
```

Proposed solution:

```
A.so
   \ declares and call "void check_backend()"

B.so
   \ implements "void check_backend()"
```